# FOSUserBundle login path not found in prod env but works in dev env

Tags: php, symfony

I've checked many posts here and on other pages and nothin worked.
I have a clean Ubuntu 16 PHP 7 setup and fresh Symfony 2.8 app + FOSUserBundle.

I need to mention that I have the same configuration on my local VM and all is working fine. I also have three other apps with the same configuration, but they are on separate servers. All of them are working fine.

In dev env (app_dev.php) all is working fine. I can see login and register FOS pages - I did not overwrite them yet. I don't even have any page except the one that is default in SYmfony. When I switch to prod (just remove app_dev.php) login and register paths don't work. I cleared cache using command, I warmed up the cache, I even removed the cache folders (dev and prod with rm -rf). Nothing worked. My configuration is the simplest one taken from Symfony website [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

My routing, security and config are exactly like in the doc on Symfony page.

I'm not new with Symfony and I've done this configuration many times but I had never had this problem.

I use Symfony 2.8 for all my projects. I even migrated two of them from 2.3 and 2.6 to 2.8 without any problems.

Any help appreciated.

UPDATE: When in prod env it doesn't even create log and cache. MOD rewrite is enabled.

UPDATE: I just discovered that if I add app.php before login then it works. So it's something about apache2 configuration. MOD rewrite is enabled. What else can I check? .htaccess is untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED.

It wasn't Symfony or apache2 config. As I use rsync to deploy to my dev server I have exclude.txt file and .* there. It wasn't sending .htaccess file to my server.

I'm adding this answer for other as a signal taht sometimes you need to look for an answer somewhere else than you think.